# carouFredSel add class to active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I'm trying to add a class of "active" to the current slide in carouFredSel, and I can't get it to work. The closest I could get it to work was to add it on the first slide, using `trigger("currentVisible")`, but it doesn't update.

Help! Thanks :)

Comment: I needed it on a button inside the slide... ended up binding a click event to that button with `$active = $('#modeles .block:first-child');`, `#modeles` being my carouFredSel wrapper, and `.block` being the slides.

Answer (score 6):

So far, I used this function ( it doesn't work on page load though and it seems to be a lot of code for that simple task)
Maybe someone has an idea how to simplify this and also make it work on page load

```
function highlight( items ) {
items.filter(":eq(1)").addClass("active");
}
function unhighlight( items ) {
items.removeClass("active");
}

$('#foo').carouFredSel({
scroll : {
onBefore: function( data ) {
  unhighlight( data.items.old );
},
onAfter : function( data ) {
  highlight( data.items.visible );
}
},
});
```

Here's an update that should work fine on page load and scroll:
[Here](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/code-examples/custom-events.php) are more details about the trigger event.

```
var $highlight = function() { 
    var $this = $("#foo");

    var items = $this.triggerHandler("currentVisible");     //get all visible items
    $this.children().removeClass("active");                 // remove all .active classes
    items.filter(":eq(1)").addClass("active");              // add .active class to n-th item
};


$('#foo').carouFredSel({

    scroll : {
        onAfter : $highlight
    },      
    onCreate    : $highlight

});
```

Comment: I know there is the parameter onCreate

Answer (score 0):

scroll : {
        onAfter : $highlight
    }

solved my issue